# How do I know when all threads in a ExecutorService are finished?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I know that `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` exist. The problem is that the runnables in the pool need to be able to add an unknown number (can't use a countdownlatch) of other runnables to it and if I call `shutdown()` those tasks will be rejected. How can I know when they're done?

Comment: When a task (`Runnable`) T spawns another n tasks, would you say this task T is done when all these n tasks are done? So is there a (conceptual) dependency between task T and its subtasks?

Comment: Right.  I left out that I'm using a `newFixedThreadPool` where the max number of running threads is the number of processors.  Once one runnable spawns the others, there's no more work for it to do.  If it waited until the runnables it spawned finished, it would just be sitting there doing nothing and the program would never end because of the bound on the number of threads.

Comment: Therefore you should probably use a `ForkJoinTask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of submitting `Runnable` tasks to an `Executor`, you should rather use [`ForkJoinTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html)/[`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) instead. A `ForkJoinTask` runs inside a `ForkJoinPool` and can spawn an arbitrary number of (sub)tasks and wait for them to complete, without actually blocking the current thread. A `ForkJoinTask` is complete when all of its sub-tasks are done, so the entire computation is done, when the initial (root) `ForkJoinTask` is complete.

See [Oracle - The Java™ Tutorials - Fork/Join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) for details.

As all of your tasks are resultless (`Runnable`), you should subclass `RecursiveAction` (which is itself a subclass of `ForkJoinTask`). Implement the method `compute()`, and spawn an arbitrary number of new tasks there by either calling `invoke(subtask)`, `invokeAll(subtask1, subtask2, ...)` or `subtask.fork()` followed by `subtask.join()`.

The entire computation is executed as follows:

```
MyRecursiveAction task = new MyRecursiveAction(params);
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(numberOfThreads);
pool.invoke(task); // will block until task is done
```

Unfortunatley the advantages of Fork/Join have some limitations, e.g.:

> (...) Computations should ideally avoid synchronized methods or blocks, and
>   should minimize other blocking synchronization apart from joining
>   other tasks or using synchronizers such as Phasers that are advertised
>   to cooperate with fork/join scheduling. Subdividable tasks should also
>   not perform blocking I/O, and should ideally access variables that are
>   completely independent of those accessed by other running tasks. These
>   guidelines are loosely enforced by not permitting checked exceptions
>   such as IOExceptions to be thrown. (...)

For more detail see [API docs of `ForkJoinTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html).

Answer (score 2):

Work with [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) rather than with `Runnable`. There's this [`Future#isDone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone--) method that may help you.

In case you don't have anything meaningful to return from the `Callable`, use `Callable<Void>` and `Future<Void>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use [Guava Futures](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html), you can use `Futures.allAsList` or `Futures.successfulAsList`. This allows you to wrap a number of `Future` instances that you got back from the `ExecutorService` into a single `Future` which you can then check to see if it is finished using `isDone()` (or just `get()`, for that matter, if you want to block until completion).