# Can a nested ExecutorService run in parallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing, fork-join, forkjoinpool

**Edit:** Changed the title and reformatted my code: (Pleas bear with my questions, i am new to this parallel world)

Instead of using FJPool, i am using ExecutorService now to parallelize my tasks. All tasks and subtasks are independent and can run in parallel without any conflict. Here is my code snippet:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
executor.submit(() -> someTask(args1);
executor.submit(() -> someTask(args2);
// Wait for tasks to complete and shutdown executor


private static void someTask( ... ) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    // executor runs a bunch of tasks in parallel here and then shutdown executor
}
```

My question is if i need to adjust number of thread pool since 2 tasks running in parallel try to create thread pool of the size of # of available cores? Will this work or will this block one of the initial task until we release the threads by shutting down?

===== **Initial question** =====

My question is slightly different that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450892/how-do-i-know-when-all-threads-in-a-executorservice-are-finished) question.
I have 2 tasks, someTask1 and someTask2 which i am planning to parallelize. The problem is (i am not sure if this could be a problem or not) that someTask1 uses ForkJoinPool and runs a bunch of other tasks in parallel. Can I parallelize the 2 tasks someTask1 and someTask2 using ForkPoolJoin something like the code below even though one of the task i am parallelizing runs other tasks in parallel? If its possible can i get some help on refactoring the code below:

```
ForkPoolJoin forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
if (someCond1) {
    forkJoinPool.submit(() -> someTask1( ... ));
}
if (someCond2) {
    forkJoinPool.submit(() -> someTask2( ... ));
}
// I want to wait here until forkJoinPool is done with both tasks (or either of the 1 based on each condition)?

private void someTask1( ... ) {
    ForkPoolJoin forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
    try {
        forkJoinPool.submit(() -> someStream.stream().map( ... ))
                    .get(); // Wait for all the tasks to complete
    } finally {
        forkJoinPool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I figured out a way to deal with the waiting issue. My solution is since i only have 2 tasks in parallel, i store the result of the forkJoinPool.submit into 2 Future variables and call on their get() function one by one. If someone else has a better more generic solution, that would be great.

Comment: The second FJPool is a bad idea. You're doubling the amount of threads, memory etc. Then parallelStream uses the common FJPool. That's the  third FJPool. I'm not going to redesign this without knowing the full requirements. Also, look into using the CountedCompleter() class. You have multiple tasks doing different work (more like Task Parallelism instead of Data Parallelism.)

Comment: @edharned sorry the parallel stream was a typo. I updated that to stream. My only question left here is if i can use FJPool within FJPool?
Can i restruct my code so that the first FJP:
ForkPoolJoin forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(2); // since i have only 2 tasks here
And the nested FJP be:
ForkPoolJoin forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism - 2);

Comment: Multiple FJPools are a bad design, period. You seem to be missing the basic concept of FJ. Wait a while, somebody may dive into this and give you an a solution.

Comment: @edharned thanks for the explanation. Any high level suggestion on how to implement this? What i am really trying to do is parallelize the top level 2 tasks, but one of them already uses FJP. I can rewrite the nested function as well and use a different approach to parallelize.

Comment: You don't have code issue, you have a design issue. Without knowing the full requirements I cannot recommend a solution. My original comment was not to use multiple FJPools. Simple solutions usually work best. Break this down into it's basic parts: no lambda, no stream, just fork() new tasks (of the CountedCompleter() class) so you don't need join() and see if that works. Then you can make it pretty.

Comment: @edharned I refactored my code and now using ExecutorService now instead of FJP. Do i still have a design/coding issue here?

Comment: Instead of two FJPools you now have three ExecutorServices. You're making an effort but you're  missing some basic understanding and I don't know what that is. Hopefully, someone else will pick up this question and give you an answer.

Comment: Thanks @edharned. I came up with one more final change. I created the ExecutorService as a class member so in that case, now i am only creating one ExecutorService and submitting all the tasks and subtasks to it since they all are independent anyways.